# closing wizard and run dialogs

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a `Wizard` that have one `page`. In the `performFinish` methos of wizard class, I want to close the wizard and run some dialogs of another plugin.

When I write the below code, It is not closed, it is just non visible.

```
getShell().setVisible(false);
```

When I wite `getShell().close()` or `dialog.close()` or `wizard.dispose()` the dialogs not appeared. What should I do?

The dialogs are opened in another plugin with such a below code.

```
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow win =wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
CreateDialog UD = new CreateDialog(win.getShell());
UD.open();
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal verifiable example? In this code I cannot see the intention you are writing about in your question.

Comment: in `performFinish` you only have to return true and nothing more

Answer (score 0):

If you want your wizard to close before the new dialog opens you will have to arrange for the dialog to run asynchronously. You can do this using `Display.asyncExec`. Something like:

```
@Override
public boolean performFinish()
{
  ... other work ...

  Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(() ->
    {
      IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
      IWorkbenchWindow win =wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
      CreateDialog UD = new CreateDialog(win.getShell());
      UD.open();
    });

  return true;
}
```

(this is Java 8, if you are using an earlier Java use a `Runnable`).

The code in the `asyncExec` block will not run until after the wizard has closed.